# Linq GetTable< > return empty rows

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a very strange problem.  I followed an MVC tutorial.

I have an interface:

```
namespace DomainModel.Abstract
{
    public interface IProductsRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
    }
}
```

A repository inherits that interface:

```
namespace DomainModel.Concrete
{
    public class SqlProductsRepository : IProductsRepository
    {
        private Table<Product> productsTable;
        public SqlProductsRepository(string connectionString)
        {
            try
            {
                productsTable = (new DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable<Product>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        public IQueryable<Product> Products
        {
            get { return productsTable; }
        }
    }
}
```

My Product class looks like this:

```
namespace DomainModel.Entities
{
    [Table(Name = "Products")]
    public class Product
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }       
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
namespace WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {

        private IProductsRepository productsRepository;
        public ProductsController()
        {
            string connString = @"Data Source=INFO_KW-HZ7YX91;Initial Catalog=SportStore;Integrated Security=True";
            productsRepository = new SqlProductsRepository(connString);

        }
        public ViewResult List()
        {
            return View(productsRepository.Products.ToList());

        }

    }
}
```

My Products table has 8 rows.  When I run the web site,  It displays 8 rows but they are all blanks and zero.  When I debugged it, I can see productsTable has 8 rows with correct column names, but the string data are null and the integer data are zero.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How do you manage to call `Dispose` on your DataContext instance if you don't retain a reference to it? You are disposing your DataContext at the end of every single request, so its database connection can be returned to the connection pool, right? Leaving something like an open database connection for the garbage collector to clean up is never a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

It has been quite a while since last time I did custom attributes like this, but I guess you need to put `[Column]` for all properties you need to persist. Something like:

```
    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Category { get; set; }       
    [Column]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

assuming that your sql table field names match the property names accordingly.

Comment: Oops, I forgot [Column] attribute.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add [Column] attributes to any of your columns but your PK.  LinqToSql is very attribute heavy, and hand-coding the classes will be fraught with risk and (most likely) frightening exceptions.  You should use sqlmetal.exe or your own generator.