# Unable to display DB table data in View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio

I have a `DataContext` created by dragging and dropping tables from my database explorer into the O/R designer .
When I try the following code in the controller, nothing is displayed in my view

```
Table<week> weektab = context.GetTable<week>();
var report = from w in weektab select new myModel(){col1, col2...};
return PartialView(report);
```

My Partialview is strongly typed and I display the Model's fields in a `foreach` loop. The code works for other tables but doesn't display anything for the `Week` table. What am I missing?

**EDIT 1 :** I verified that the `Week` table has 110 rows.

**EDIT 2 :**
here is the code
**`Model`**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace proj.Models
{
    public class WeeklyReportModel
    {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string mon { get; set; }
    public string tue { get; set; }
    public string wed { get; set; }
    public string thu { get; set; }
    public string fri { get; set; }
    public string sat { get; set; }
}
```

}
**`Controller snippet`**

```
public PartialViewResult showResult(string unit, string day)
    {
        this.context = new projDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
        ...
        Table<week> weektab = context.GetTable<week>();
         ...
        var report = from sat1 in weektab
                            select new WeeklyReportModel{ name = sat1.col1};

        return PartialView(report);
    }<br/>
```

**`PartialView`**

```
@using proj.Models
@model IEnumerable<WeeklyReportModel>

<table>
    ...
            @foreach (var p in Model)
            {
                <tr>

                    <td>@p.name</td>
                    <td>@p.mon</td>
                      <td>@p.tue</td>
                      <td>@p.wed</td>
                      <td>@p.thu</td>
                      <td>@p.fri</td>
                      <td>@p.sat</td>
                </tr>
            }
</table>
```

Comment: Have you run the project in debug and confirmed that your report object contains data?

Comment: @markpsmith i ran the project in debug mode and tried displaying the data within the controller itself using a foreach loop and a response.write within it but the loop isnt executing

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line after: 'var report=from w in week....' and run it in debug, you will be able to hover over the report variable and see its value.

Comment: thank you @markpsmith i tried it and it shows the sql code for the report variable.i ran the code in sql server ,appending the database name to [dbo].[week] and i t works fine in sql server but doesnt work in my application

Comment: could someone pls answer my question..??

Comment: Can you post the query, the model, and the partial view please?

Comment: @markpsmith i have done it...pls note that if the table week is replaced with the table abc the query returns data

Comment: Looks ok... What do you see if your put a breakpoint on the line '@foreach (var p in Model)' and hover over 'Model'?

Comment: @markpsmith i get the same query as in report..i tried clicking on the result view in the hover box and it said "enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: When you are at that breakpoint, can you open the Quick View window (shift+f9) and see what Model.ToList() evaluates as?

Comment: @markpsmith sorry to say i dont have the quickwatch..i did Model.toList() in watch window and got count=0

Comment: ok, that's good enough - if your count is zero, you have no data!  Go back to the breakpoint in the controller & do the same i.e. report.ToList()

Comment: @markpsmith..it also gives count=0 ....but when i query the table in sql server management studio it has 110 rows

Comment: what does the weektab table look like?

Comment: @markpsmith thanks for the debugging trail!!the weektab itself is empty but i wonder how?any ideas?

Comment: I can only think that there is a problem with the week table definition.  Is there a class that represents the week table?  I was just looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754171/linq-gettable-return-empty-rows) which seems similar to yours.

Comment: @markpsmith thank you for your support.. i will look at the table again

Comment: @markpsmith thanks a lot for your step by step help..i found out that the error was in my connection string that pointed to a previous version of my db.could you please post your previous comment as an answer so that others could benefit and i can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the request of the OP I'm posting this answer as a conclusion to the comment trail above.

I can only think that there is a problem with the week table definition. Is there a class that represents the week table? I was just looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754171/linq-gettable-return-empty-rows) which seems similar to yours

Comment: For people looking at this answer, the error was because my table was empty in a previous version of the DB and my connection string was pointing to that version